No implementation for ActorSystem<?> was bound
I'm trying to use play 3.0 with scala 3.5.
Here's my application.conf
req-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "fork-join-executor"
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-min = 8
    parallelism-factor = 3.0
    parallelism-max = 64
  }
  throughput = 1
}

Module.scala
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import config.{RequestExecutionContext, RequestExecutionContextImpl}
import javax.inject._
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.ScalaModule
import play.api.{Configuration, Environment}

class Module(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration)
  extends AbstractModule
    with ScalaModule {

  override def configure() = {
    bind[RequestExecutionContext].to[RequestExecutionContextImpl].in[Singleton]()
  }
}

RequestExecutionContext.scala
package config

import org.apache.pekko.actor.typed.ActorSystem

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.libs.concurrent.CustomExecutionContext

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

trait RequestExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext

@Singleton
class RequestExecutionContextImpl @Inject() (system: ActorSystem[_]) extends
  CustomExecutionContext(system.classicSystem, "req-dispatcher") with RequestExecutionContext

This is the error
play.api.PlayException: Execution exception[[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) [Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for ActorSystem<?> was bound.

Requested by:
1  : config.RequestExecutionContextImpl.<init>(RequestExecutionContext.scala:18)
      \_ for 1st parameter system
     at Module.configure(scala.scala:12)
      \_ installed by: Modules$OverrideModule -> Module

Learn more:
  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/MISSING_IMPLEMENTATION

1 error

======================
Full classname legend:
======================
ActorSystem:            "org.apache.pekko.actor.typed.ActorSystem"
Modules$OverrideModule: "com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule"
========================
End of classname legend:
========================
]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.convertToPlayException$$anonfun$3(HttpErrorHandler.scala:407)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.convertToPlayException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:407)
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:390)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$DevServerApplicationProvider$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:265)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$DevServerApplicationProvider$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:190)
    at play.core.server.PekkoHttpServer.handleRequest(PekkoHttpServer.scala:320)
    at play.core.server.PekkoHttpServer.$anonfun$3(PekkoHttpServer.scala:224)
    at org.apache.pekko.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsyncUnordered$$anon$31.onPush(Ops.scala:1443)
    at org.apache.pekko.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:555)
    at org.apache.pekko.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:506)
    at org.apache.pekko.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:400)
    at org.apache.pekko.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:662)
    at org.apache.pekko.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:532)
    at org.apache.pekko.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:637)
    at org.apache.pekko.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.org$apache$pekko$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:813)
    at org.apache.pekko.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anon$2.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:831)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:481)
    at org.apache.pekko.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:729)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:280)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:253)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)

Can someone point out at what I am missing here?

Sounds like you should be using org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorSystem (i.e. the not typed version) and ask for injection of a plain ActorSystem (not generic).

Alternatively to make Guide happy - wrap actor system with some non parametric class, so that type erasure would not confuse runtime reflection. And extract it everywhere you need it.
